# HP Wlan button and led dont't work

Tags: debian, wlan, hp

I have a Compaq CQ58 laptop with fresh Debian 12. I would like to fix one problem, namely the non-working WLAN on/off button. Constantly lights up yellow (it should be either yellow or blue) and does not respond to pressing. `xev` does not catch its pressing.

Comment: @A.B, oh, sorry. I solved problem with WLAN button with your answer! Many thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian 12 ships with the latest Linux LTS when it was released: Linux 6.1

For the 6.1 version the driver handling WMI keys exists:

[`CONFIG_HP_WMI`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/HP_WMI.html):

> HP WMI extras found in `drivers/platform/x86/Kconfig`
>
> The configuration item CONFIG_HP_WMI:
>
> - prompt: HP WMI extras
> - [...]
> - found in Linux kernels: 2.6.29–2.6.39, 3.0–3.19, 4.0–4.20, 5.0–5.19, 6.0–6.1
>   modules built: `hp-wmi`, `hp-wmi`, `hp-wmi`
>
> [...]
>
> Say Y here if you want to **support WMI-based hotkeys on HP laptops** and
> to read data from WMI such as docking or ambient light sensor state.

But actually there's an additional toggle to get this option: [`X86_PLATFORM_DRIVERS_HP`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/X86_PLATFORM_DRIVERS_HP.html) which appeared in 6.2 and was [backported to 6.1](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/drivers/platform/x86/hp/Kconfig?h=linux-6.1.y&id=1189b7f4954084a5cfb10ab48f4e41fc9c37b516) later. This created a regression, because this new option wasn't enabled in Debian's kernel 6.1:

```shell
$ grep CONFIG_X86_PLATFORM_DRIVERS_HP /boot/config-6.1.0-12-amd64
# CONFIG_X86_PLATFORM_DRIVERS_HP is not set
```

resulting in no `CONFIG_HP_WMI` option appearing at all in Debian's kernel. Older kernels (such as `linux-image-6.1.0-9-amd64`) still provided this driver.

---

### What can be done now?

- Debian 12 offers currently in backports [Linux 6.4.4](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm-backports/linux-image-amd64) (pulling `linux-image-6.4.0-0.deb12.2-amd64`) which does enable this option and thus does provide the `hp_wmi` kernel module.

  Instructions on activating backports: https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/
- Or you can use https://snapshot.debian.org/ in a similar way to use the latest provided kernel before the regression: `linux-image-6.1.0-9-amd64` (does include `hp_wmi`).

Once booted in an adequate kernel, please verify that the module `hp_wmi` (from file `hp-wmi.ko`) is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep hp_wmi
```

If not, as root (so using first `su -` or `sudo -i`) attempt to load it with:

```
modprobe hp_wmi
```

If it tells nothing chances are it's working. If it returns something like:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'hp_wmi': No such device
```

that would mean this answer didn't solve the problem (ie: the module doesn't recognize the current hardware).

---

### What should be done later?

- Using a -backports kernel is not recommended, because it doesn't receive any timely security update. Likewise, keeping an older kernel means it's not updated.
- Switching the kernel to a testing/unstable kernel, while not best practice would be better than backports, but some adequate care must be done to avoid upgrading by mistake the whole Debian 12 into testing/unstable.

Really, you should [file a Debian bug](https://wiki.debian.org/reportbug) for [the kernel](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianKernelReportingBugs) (can't tell if this should be for `kernel` or for `linux`) asking that `CONFIG_X86_PLATFORM_DRIVERS_HP` and `HP_WMI` get enabled in Debian 12's stable kernel because it's causing a regression.